# addListener Event -- error

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

I am trying to build a event handler between the rows and data points.  I am currently getting an error:

> TypeError: line.getSelection is not a function.

I am little unsure, how to add this feature or where I may be going wrong:

```
        var table = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
            'chartType': 'Table',
            'containerId': 'TableContainer',
            'options': { 'height': '25em', 'width': '80em' }
        });

        new google.visualization.Dashboard(document.getElementById('PieChartExample')).bind([myIdSlider], [line, table]).draw(data);
        table.draw(data, { showRowNumber: true });

        google.visualization.events.addListener(line, 'select', function () {
            table.setSelection([{ row: line.getSelection()[0].row }]);
        });

        google.visualization.events.addListener(table, 'select', function () {
            line.setSelection(table.getSelection());
        });

       // table.setSelection([{ row: chart.getSelection()[0].row }]);


    }
```

Any help would be very much appreciated. Many thanks.

Comment: I can't see where line variable is declared.

Comment: No line declared. However, try window.getSelection()

Comment: Thank you all for your response.  I tried adding the 'window' line, but it output the same error response as 'line.window' undefined.  I am also getting a another warning error -- Empty string passed to getElementById().  This warning is linked to the error, i believe, because it increments count whenever i click on the table rows. Please advice. Thank you

Comment: Could you show your complete code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your `line` variable is a ChartWrapper (like `table`), you need to use this:

```
google.visualization.events.addListener(line, 'select', function () {
    var lineSelection = line.getChart().getSelection();
    var tableSelection = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < lineSelection.length; i++) {
        // iterate over lineSelection, since it could potentially contain multiple or 0 elements
        // check to see if "row" property is defined, since clicking on the legend fires a select event with no "row" property
        if (lineSelection[i].row != null) {
            tableSelection.push({row: lineSelection[i].row});
        }
    }
    table.getChart().setSelection(tableSelection);
});

google.visualization.events.addListener(table, 'select', function () {
    var tableSelection = table.getChart().getSelection();
    var lineSelection = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < lineSelection.length; i++) {
        // iterate over lineSelection, since it could potentially contain multiple or 0 elements
        lineSelection.push({
            row: tableSelection[i].row,
            column: /* choose a column to select */
        });
        // you may add more selections here if you want to select points from multiple data series
    }
    line.getChart().setSelection(lineSelection);
});
```

Comment: This is great help. I really appreciate your help, time and hardwork into this explanation/solution.  Many thanks =D